# Clarifying use of an already declared variable within a for loop that iterates through a list

Tags: python, string, list

I don't understand why after declaring the variable animal as the string 'Peacock', you are able to use it in the for loop such that it outputs the smallest character in each list element. What does animal in the for loop represent?

I originally thought it would check if the string peacock was in the list element, and then print out the smallest character. I am looking for a general explanation of how this code works if possible.

The output for this code is:
G
A
L
r

```
animal='Peacock'
for animal in ['Giraffe','Alligator','Liger']:
    print(min(animal))
print(max(animal))
```

Comment: Where is the code with the string Peacock ?

Comment: min(animal) print the smallest ascii value char

Comment: Updated with the code, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: you variable outside loop is being overwritten by the values of list inside the loop, so the value 'Peacock' will eventually be lost the moment you used it on the list to iterate items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare a variable call `animal`:

```
animal='Peacock'
```

now you erase the content of your variable animal which will contain successively `'Giraffe'` then `'alligator'` and then `'Liger'` as it will become successively each element of the list:

```
for animal in ['Giraffe','Alligator','Liger']:
    print(min(animal))
print(max(animal))
```

to understand better you can run:

```
animal='Peacock'
print(animal)
for animal in ['Giraffe','Alligator','Liger']:
    print(animal)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain step by step:

- You first iterate through the list `['Giraffe','Alligator','Liger']`, which will give you `Giraffe` the first iteration, and so on...
- Then you get the minimum value of the string (who would want to do that :P), which is `G`, then `A`, then `L`, since when you get the `ord(your number here)` of them and it get's the minimum from the list of `ord`s of the values.
- The last line will give the maximum value of the `animal`, which is the last element since that exits the loop, so the maximum value of `Liger` is `r`, since it's `ord` is the biggest.

So that's the reason, also `Peacock` gets out of your code after it is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is actually finding the minimum character in each of the list: Meaning, since G has the lowest precedence in 'Giraffe', G is printed out.

Example given

[image]